# Проблема в подключение БД Mysqli

Tags: php, база-данных, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Ошибка :

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\Users\Filip\Desktop\OSPanel\domains\mynewchat.com\configAndDb\db.php on line 9

Код config.php :

```
<?php 

$config = array
  (
 "title" => "Мой блог";
 "db" => array
   (
"username" => "root",   
"server" => "localhost",    
"password" => "",
"name" => "myportfolio" 
   )
 )

require "db.php";
?>
```

Код db.php :

```
<?php 


 $connection = mysqli_connect
(
 $config["db"]["user"],
 $config["db"]["username"],
 $config["db"]["server"],
 $config["db"]["password"]
)



?>
```

Comment: Ну серьезно - вы не видите что у вас два ключа `user` и `username`?

Comment: охх , невнимательность

Comment: u_mulder но это сути не меняет , ошибка прежняя

Comment: Что изменилось в коде?

Comment: Это разве так важно? ну user на name поменял

Comment: Да откройте уже мануал официальный и изучите порядок аргументов. Поменял он.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91159/discussion-between-luric-and-u-mulder).

Answer (score 1):

У меня такой конфиг и все работает. Может возьми себе такой? (Там **$database** и **define** поменяй на свой, если будеш етот вариант брать)

```
<?php 

    # Настройки:    
    $host = 'localhost'; // Не меняй если локалка!!! Если не локалка, меняй на название своего хоста
    $database = 'physics'; // Название твоей БД, если нету, сделать!!!
    $dbUser = 'mysql'; // Логин, если не реестировался на phpMyAdmin не меняй!!!
    $dbPassword = 'mysql'; // Пароль, если не реестировался на phpMyAdmin не меняй!!!
    define("URL", "http://super-fizuka.com/"); // Напиши по какому юрл будет открываться твой сайт!!!
```